# let $I_k=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{p(x)}dx$ for which $k$ is $I_k$ smaller?

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let $p(x)=2+4x+3x^2+5x^3+3x^4+4x^5+2x^6$.For which $k$ with $0 \lt k\lt 5$,define $$I_k=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{p(x)}dx$$. For which $k$ is $I_k$ smaller?

When i was dealing with this question, i thought to manipulate p(x) to get a nicer integral but it didn't worked, then I saw this solution:

with substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$, one finds that$$I_k=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{p(x)}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{4-k}}{p(x)}dx=I_{4-k}$$

afterward, $$I_k=\frac{I_k+I_{4-k}}{2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{x^k+x^{4-k}}{2}}{p(x)}dx$$
then,we can say that:$$I_k\gt\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{p(x)}dx=I_2\,\,[ \frac{x^k+x^{4-k}}{2} \gt (x^k.x^{4-k})^\frac{1}{2}]$$ $\implies I_k$ smaller for $k=2$.

great! But, i want to ask that how people come with such clever and creative solutions? Also if you have any other creative solution please share it and explain your thought process behind it.

Comment: This trick works if the polynomial coefficients have to be symmetric.

Comment: Perhaps, it is possible to reduce the comparison problem only to compar

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of arbitrary problem that does not generalize well.  (For instance, what would happen if you changed a few of the coefficients in $p(x)$?)

So just apply trivial numerical integration and be done with it:

{0.0879451, 0.0682201, 0.0879451, 0.221379, 95794.8}

Indeed, $k=2$ is the minimum.

[image]

Comment: Did you even read the rest of the question....

Comment: K.defaoite:  Yes I did.  My question about the foundation of your question remains.  The answer to "how did someone come up with a solution" often has the vague (but accurate) answer:  they were creative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it is possible to reduce the comparison problem only to the comparison of $\int x^k$ by applying the product rule to get rid of the influence of $p(x)$ on $x^k$ under the integral sign.
Then compare simply by using the power rule.